# Facebook.init() doesn't work and I don't see any errors.

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating a flash application and I downloaded GraphAPI_web_1.8.1.swc. And I am using adobe flash professional cs6 and created a project with as3. I have a log in button and when I click it, it should connect me to the Facebook by my application. It doesn't work and I don't see any errors on compiler window. But I traced every steps and I saw the init and login functions doesn't work. I was trying Facebook desktop instead of Facebook web and I worked with air but not with flash professional. And I decided to This is my code.

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import com.facebook.graph.Facebook;

public class Main extends MovieClip {

    private var APP_ID:String = "466097573423642";  
    public var permissions:Array = ["user_birthday","read_stream","publish_stream","email"];

    public function Main() {
        // constructor code
        loginout.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _login);
        Facebook.init(APP_ID, loginHandler);
    }

    private function _login(e:MouseEvent):void
    {

        Facebook.login(loginHandler, permissions);
        trace("clicked");
    }

    protected function loginHandler(success:Object, fail:Object):void
    {
        trace("Hey");
        if(success) {
            trace("Login successful!");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try importing this also:

```
import com.facebook.graph.net.FacebookRequest;
import com.facebook.graph.utils.FacebookDataUtils;
import com.facebook.graph.controls.Distractor;
```

Comment: I dont get any error. thats why it wont work. but anyway thanks for answering